# Getting optimal rows based on two variables (Shipment_time, Shipment cost)

Tags: pandas, postgresql, pareto-optimality

I am trying determine optimal solution based on two variables(columns) being time and cost. I need to decide which Shipment provider is most optimal based on delivery time and delivery cost.

I would like to know if there is any way to do it in SQL or Python(Pandas). The values are something like:

| delivery time | delivery cost |
| --- | --- |
| "1 day 24:55:38.765958" | 11.3057446808510638 |
| "2 days 13:44:12.084918" | 8.6606336633663366 |
| "2 days 21:47:49" | 13.0000000000000000 |
| "2 days 28:21:07.42914" | 35.5322866894197952 |

Comment: What is your definition of optimality?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure either. I am still brain storm how to find best combination of two variables, making delivery time important but still taking into consideration cost of transport.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of pareto-optimal is that you want every row which has no rows which are better than it in both dimensions.  That translates pretty readily into SQL:

```
select * from foo a where not exists (
    select 1 from foo b where b.delivery_time<a.delivery_time and b.delivery_cost < a.delivery_cost
);
```

I'm not sure what you should do in case of ties, though.

Comment: To be honest I am still brain storm how to find best combination of two variables, making delivery time important but still taking into consideration cost of transport.  I will up vote your answer for the effort and I thank you for it. I think that my final answer will be less scientific and more qualitative.